# RestAssured - what is the difference between get() and getString() when parsing responses?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have the following two methods get() and getString() used in the following way:

```
String resString = res.asString();
JsonPath j = new JsonPath(resString);

String r = j.getString("'Meta Data'");
```

and

```
String responseString = res.asString();
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responseString);

String placeid = js.get("place_id");
```

In both cases, I'm converting the responses from raw to string to JSON. In the second one, using get gives the string at the 'place_id' path. When I use get for the first one; however, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at basics5AdvancedExtract.Test(basics5AdvancedExtract.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I got what I needed after some trial and error with getString(). Why doesn't get work in the first case? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think the core issue here is you're only considering the specific json you're parsing, you may well have a reference to one node in a JSON object that has other objects inside of it, for example, consider the following:

```
{
    foo: "bar",
    bar: {
         baz: "42",
    },
}
```

If you used `json.get("foo")`, it'd return an object which represents a string, and if you did `json.getString("foo")`, it should (in theory) also be a string

***But what if you did*** `json.getString("bar")`?

You can't represent that as a string, it's an object!

Comment: Appreciate the response! String r = j.getString("'Meta Data'") actually contains an object and works though. Also, when I print r out, it prints what is specified at that path. Based on the error, it seems getString() converts the HashMap into a string whereas get does not.